# Custom UITableViewCell disappear for TableView when shown in DetailViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

**Here's the logic** :

-> `UITableView` with customs cells 
-> `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` is added to custom cell in `cellForRowAt`
-> When custom cell is pressed, `DetailViewController` is pushed with `NavigationController`
-> `DetailViewController` display the custom cell correctly

**The issue** :

-> When going back to the main `ViewController`, the custom cell is missing from the `TableView`
-> A space if left where it was before...
-> It's impossible to select again or anything...

**My question** :

-> Can someone please explain to me why this is happening and how to fix it ? 
-> Obviously I don't want this cell to disappear from the `TableView` when going back to it...

**And here's the code** :

*1 - View Controller*

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return myArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

// table view cell setup
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ChatMessageCell
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle.none
    let chatMessage = myArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.messageLabel.text = chatMessage.text
    cell.chatMessage = chatMessage

// add gesture recognizer to cell
    let recognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer()
    recognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(longPressHappened(sender:)))
    cell.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)

    return cell
}

@objc func longPressHappened(sender:UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == .began {
        guard let selectedCell = sender.view as? ChatMessageCell else { return }
        if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "Detail") as? DetailViewController {
            vc.cellToShow = selectedCell
            navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
}
```

*2 - Detail View Controller*

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    var cellToShow: ChatMessageCell!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(cellToShow)
    }
}
```

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A view can only has 1 parent at a time , so when you add it to the detailvc which isn't a right action for cells to be subviews of anything other than tables , it's get removed from the table